# Sass Color Functions List Gradient

Tags: css, colors, haml, sass

I'm trying to assigne a different `background-color` to each `%li` tag in my list. I'd like those colors to either use shades of a color, or gradient between two stated colors. Much like the oh-so-popular [Clear](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clear/id493136154?mt=8). I'm familiar with the ability to lighten and darken colors with sass...

```
$this_color: darken($that_color, 10%)
```

But beyond that I don't know how to create the affect I'm looking for. Visually here is what I am trying to do:

```
%ul
    %li full color
    %li darken 5%
    %li darken 10%
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it
change the colors one by one in the loop
http://jsfiddle.net/STuD5/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
// set your color
$backgroundColor: red

// set the scale/increment for the function
$backgroundColorScale: 8

// number of items in your list
$numberOfItemsInList: 10

// here's a custom function to change the color
// but you could make this fairly advanced
// and shift color, saturate, etc.
@function -modify-bg($bgcolor, $counter, $depth: $backgroundColorScale)
  @return lighten($backgroundColor, ($i * $backgroundColorScale))

// here's the loop that steps through LIs and assigns each a new bg
$i: 0
@while $i < $numberOfItemsInList
  li:nth-child(#{$i})
    background-color: -modify-bg($backgroundColor, $i)
  $i: $i + 1
```